# How to give access restriction to DLL's in .net

Tags: .net

I have a 3 layer application(UI,Business Layer,Data Layer).My requirement is my datalayer should be only accessible by business layer,and the business layer should be only accessible by UI layer.

That means even if i add a reference of adtalayer in the UI layer,it should not be able to access the methods in Datalayer.

I should be able to create DLL's with access protection.

please suggest a solution for this?

Thanks

SC

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the constructors of key classes or methods in your business and data layers as `internal` and then use the [InternalVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute to extend that access to the appropriate assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like what you're looking for is called "policy injection". I'm not sure if this is the easiest or best way, but [PostSharp](http://postsharp.org) will do what you want.